# Removing all columns with a name on the fly

Tags: r, readxl

I'm using `read_excel` for speed and simplicity to import an Excel file.

Unfortunately, there's as yet no capability of excluding selected columns which won't be needed from the data set; to save effort, I am naming such columns `"x"` with the `col_names` argument, which is easier than trying to keep track of `x1`, `x2`, and so on.

I'd then like to exclude such columns on the fly if possible to avoid an extra step of copying, so in pseudocode:

```
read_excel("data.xlsx", col_names = c("x", "keep", "x"))[ , !"x"]
```

We can use the sample data set included with the `readxl` package for illustration:

```
library(readxl)
DF <- read_excel(system.file("extdata/datasets.xlsx", package = "readxl"),
                 col_names = c("x", "x", "length", "width", "x"), skip = 1L)
```

The approaches I've seen that work don't exactly work on the fly, e.g., having stored `DF`, we can now do:

```
DF <- DF[ , -grep("^x$", names(DF))]
```

This works but requires making a copy of `DF` by storing it, then overwriting it; I'd prefer to remove the columns in the same command as `read_excel` to allocate `DF` properly *ab initio*.

Other similar approaches require declaring temporary variables, which I prefer to avoid if possible, e.g.,

```
col_names <- c("x", "x", "length", "width", "x")
DF <- read_excel(system.file("extdata/datasets.xlsx", package = "readxl"),
                 col_names = col_names, skip = 1L)[ , -grep("^x$", col_names)]
```

Is there a way to axe these columns without creating unnecessary temporary variables?

(I could convert to `data.table`, but am wondering if there's a way to do so without `data.table`)

Comment: Are you open to using `dplyr`? You can pipe that into `select()` without explicitly creating a variable first. (Of course, the complete data.frame will still exist whether or not you name it.) If the only problem is the extra variable, just create your own function `dropXcolumns()` or something.

Comment: About `requires making a copy of DF by storing it`: I guess that a copy is made even if you make it a one-liner, so I think yours is a no problem. The only way to avoid a copy would be if `read_excel` allowed it explicitly (something similar to the `select` argument of `data.table::fread`).

Comment: `XLConnnect::readWorksheet` (which has the better documentation, though you likely want `readWorksheetFromFile`) has `keep` and `drop` parameters for columns. It's Java-based, though, so installation is a little more complicated than usual.

Comment: @alistaire `xlsx` is the same. I have my reasons for using `read_excel` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a way to do this in `readxl::read_excel`, though it's a little hidden, and I have no idea if the columns are read into memory [temporarily] regardless. The trick is to specify column types, putting in `"blank"` for those you don't want:

```
readxl::read_excel(system.file("extdata/datasets.xlsx", package = "readxl"),
                   col_types = c('blank', 'blank', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'text'))
## # A tibble: 150 x 3
##    Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
##           <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>
## 1           1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2           1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3           1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4           1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5           1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6           1.7         0.4  setosa
## 7           1.4         0.3  setosa
## 8           1.5         0.2  setosa
## 9           1.4         0.2  setosa
## 10          1.5         0.1  setosa
## # ... with 140 more rows
```

The caveat is that you need to know all the data types of the columns you want, though I suppose you could always just start with text and clean up later with `type.convert` or whatnot.

Comment: Interesting. I've filed [#193](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues/193) with `readxl` as this is indeed quite poorly documented.

Comment: Anyway, if I understand the C++ code correctly, it's not reading anything for the `"blank"` columns, as happens (?) [here](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/blob/7c7f66b29764eee91385c9f1fc755b1ac6c10e08/src/CellType.h#L132-L141). Good work!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an easy way to avoid copying. But a one liner is achievable using piping, needing no temporary variables. E.g.:

```
library(magrittr)
read_excel(system.file("extdata/datasets.xlsx", package = "readxl"), 
           col_names = c("x", "x", "length", "width", "x"), skip = 1L) %>% 
  extract(, -grep("^x$", names(.))) -> 
  DF
```